# "Select a background image" option is not visible in Gmail

Tags: gmail, customization

“Select a background image” option is not visible in Gmail.

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to do so should be behind **Themes**. Choose *Custom Light* or *Custom Dark* first and then click on "Learn more" in the bottom left-hand corner for further advice.